# In WPF, how to set the style like fold paper tip to rectangle or any other control

Tags: wpf, styles

I have managed to style a rectangle such that there is a fold paper tip image style in top right corner side. My requirement is I need to have style with multi-document view image. I can able to achive this below xaml. Now I need to set fold paper tip image style.

Thanks in advance.

RamaS

```
<Window x:Class="ExpandTreeViewWPF.Window2"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="Window2" Height="300" Width="300">
   <Window.Resources>
      <VisualBrush x:Key="Icon">
         <VisualBrush.Visual>
            <Canvas Width="10" Height="10">

               <Rectangle  Width="20" Height="20" Fill="White"  StrokeThickness=".2" Stroke="Gray"     Canvas.Left="1" Canvas.Top="2"/>
               <Rectangle Width="20" Height="20" Fill="White" StrokeThickness=".2" Stroke="Gray"  Canvas.Left="2" Canvas.Top="1"/>
               <Rectangle Width="20" Height="20" Fill="White"  StrokeThickness=".2" Stroke="Gray"  Canvas.Left="3" Canvas.Top="0"/>
            </Canvas>
         </VisualBrush.Visual>
      </VisualBrush>
   </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
      <ListBox>
         <Border Background="{StaticResource Icon}">
         <ListBoxItem Padding="50">One</ListBoxItem>
            </Border>
         <ListBoxItem>Two</ListBoxItem>
         <ListBoxItem>Three</ListBoxItem>
      </ListBox>
   </Grid>
</Window>
```

Answer (score 0):

for outer rectangle, I set following style to Fill property.